# How to Update Array Passed Into Function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am passing an array of the sort `int * foo = new int[n]` into a method `void bar(int * foo, int size)`. My issue is, when I alter the array inside the function, I can print it and see the changes, however, in main I call another function separately to print foo and it appears to not be updating. Can someone help me with this?

Edit: Actual functions

Note: This is a coding exercise I am doing, so I cannot change the data structure to a vector, nor can I change the way the memory for the array is being stored. The only parts of the code I can edit is the blocks inside the heapRemove and heapPrint functions.

Another Edit: I changed the way I am passing the array pointer to the method. Now, it appears to update the first two items, but not the rest. Any ideas why? I updated the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int readheap(int * theheap)
{
    //your code here
    //use std::cin to read in the data
    //return the size of the heap
    int value, count;
    while ( std::cin >> value) {
        theheap[count] = value;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

void heapRemove(int *& theheap, int& size)
{
   //your code here 
    theheap[0] = theheap[size - 1];
    int tempHeapArr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        tempHeapArr[i] = theheap[i];
    }
    theheap = tempHeapArr;
    size -= 1;

    int parent = 0;
    while (true) {
        int l = (2 * parent) + 1;
        int r = l + 1;
        int minChild = l;
        if (l >= size) {
            break;
        }
        if (r < size && theheap[r] < theheap[l]) {
            minChild = r;
        }
        if (theheap[parent] > theheap [minChild]) {
            int temp = theheap[parent];
            theheap[parent] = theheap[minChild];
            theheap[minChild] = temp;
            parent = minChild;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            std::cout << theheap[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
}

void heapPrint(int * theheap, int size)
{
    //use cout to print the array representing the heap
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            std::cout << theheap[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int * theheap = new int[10];
    int size = readheap(theheap);
    heapRemove(theheap, size);
    heapPrint(theheap, size);
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: If changes inside the function aren't seen in main, then there's most likely a problem with bar()'s scoping. Are you sure changes inside bar() aren't just trashed at termination of bar()? Like with a temp array, or there's a missing "foo->" somewhere? It'd be nice to see bar()'s code, too...

Comment: I want to see `bar()` function body and how did you call it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also you (probably) shouldn't be using a raw `new`, if you're learning it for legacy reasons then that's ok, but if you're on a course that's telling you to use it, ditch the course. Prefer `std::vector` for dynamic allocation of an array.

Comment: I was trying to keep my question as general as possible, but I understand it wasn't entirely clear what I was asking. I posted my code in an edit.

Comment: @George Unfortunately I cannot alter the main function for this code. I am doing an online exercise.

Comment: You aren't passing an array to the function, you are passing a pointer to the function.

Comment: You'll need a reference to the pointer in this case. The array is passed by reference, but the pointer to it is passed by value, and you change the value of the pointer inside the function.

Comment: Similar, possibly duplicate, question: [In C++, are changes to pointers passed to a function reflected in the calling function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708383/in-c-are-changes-to-pointers-passed-to-a-function-reflected-in-the-calling-fu)

Comment: @user4581301 Well I got a message back from my teacher and learned that I can alter the way the pointer is being passed, so I'll update my code above with what I've done.

Comment: This update will have solved a problem and exposed the next problem. `int tempHeapArr[10];` is an Automatic (local) variable. It will go out of scope and become invalid (though very likely still accessible so watch out!) when `heapRemove` returns. This leaves `theheap` back in `main` pointing to Crom-knows-what and `heapPrint`'s output is unpredictable. Might look like it works, might crash, might print garbage.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah I see what you're saying. The section when I use that temp array, I am doing that as a way of deleting the last element of the array(not actually the last element, but the element at size - 1 which is the last "used" element so to speak. I don't entirely fill the array. That being said, should I just come up with a way of "deleting" the element without creating a new array, instead just altering theheap?

Comment: That should be a better approach. Eliminates a lot of potential complexity and the need to pass the pointer reference. Also worth keeping an eye on `int * theheap = new int[10];` specifying a 10 element array while `readheap` places no restrictions on how many elements can be entered. This will result in an overflow sooner or later. You  want to either resize  the array pointed to by `theheap` as needed to fit in more element  or use `std::vector` because it resizes itself as you add to it. Most of the time these assignments won't allow you to use `std::vector`, so you might want to write one.

Comment: I fixed my issue and am now getting the correct output. I simply deleted tempHeapArr and just decremented size, as size is what the logic is based off of. Thus, that last element still exists, but the program never sees it, therefore it is effectively deleted. Thanks for all the help, guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I agree. However, these assignments that I'm doing calculate the computational complexity of the code, pushing you to write minimal algorithms (for a data structures and algorithms course). Also, unfortunately, a lot of the code blocks cannot be edited by the student. I usually use std::vector and always try avoid using the new keyword.

Comment: Understood, but you must address the fact that your program will misbehave as soon as the marker inputs more than ten values. Fixing this is necessary complexity unless you have been given an upper limit on the number of inputs and can statically allocate your array to that upper limit.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code with static size of 5

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bar(int * foo, int size){
    foo[0] = 0;
    foo[1] = 1;
    foo[2] = 2;
    foo[3] = 3;
    foo[4] = 4;
}


int main(){
    int * foo = new int[5];
    bar(foo, 5);
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
       cout<<foo[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Updating the value inside bar and printing in main and it works.

Comment: This would work, but this fails to address the problem the Asker was having. To fully replicate the asker's problem, `bar` would have to point `foo` at a different array.